# I don't understand how to use an imported library in Java, in Netbeans

Tags: java, import

I have searched and read many similar questions here, but I could not figure it out using solutions others have posted. Hence the need to ask a new question.

I downloaded Apache Commons Math. I then installed the jar file to my libraries of the project I am working on (in Netbeans):

[image]

So in RSA.java, I would like to use the nextLong method, as seen [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html#nextLong%28long,%20long%29):

I have tried numerous import statements, such as:

import commons-math3-3.4.1.*;

or

import docs.apidocs.org.apache.commons.math3.*;

But regardless, it gives me "package does not exist" no matter what I try:

[image]

Comment: have you tried : import org.apache.commons.math3.random ?

Comment: `nextLong` is a *method* (not a *class*). It belongs to `RandomDataGenerator` class from `org.apache.commons.math3.random` package.

Comment: Gerard and PM 77-1, that import statement does not work. I have updated my OP with the error message to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/RandomDataGenerator.html) to locate the correct name of the class

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.random.RandomDataGenerator;
```

Comment: This does not work. I updated the OP to show an image of the error.

Comment: That jar file looks like it contains the javadoc. Try downloading the [one containing the classes themselves](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem immediately. But how did you know to download that file, instead of the files listed here:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi

That is where I am taken when I go to the download section of commons math.

Comment: Simply from the screenshot and its `api.docs...` content. Actually the download from the binaries section has a newer version of the API.